# Component is not re-rendering upon url change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

The `Router` configuration looks like following

`App.js`

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home />} />
    <Route exact path="/products/:productId" component={ ProductDetail } />
    <Redirect to="/" />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Here is how `ProductDetail` component looks like

`ProductDetail.js`

```
export const ProductDetail = ({ match }) => {
  const productId = match.params.productId;
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchProductById(productId));
  }, [productId, dispatch]);

const product = useSelector((state) => selectProductById(state, productId));
return(<.....>)
}
```

Now when I navigate from `Home` to `ProductDetail` then everything works fine. However if I try to hit url `http://localhost:3000/products/someId` directly, the component doesn't render and `useEffect` hook doesn't get called.

I have read the `Router` documentation, and it says

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component.

Shouldn't that mean the newly created component(`ProductDetail` in my case) should render and hooks get called?
I am new to `React` so I might be missing something fairly straightforward.

Comment: Does the `Home` component initialize some kind of state that `ProductDetail` depends on? By "the component doesn't render", do you mean that it renders the `Home` component or that it doesn't render anything at all?

Comment: Yes, `Home` component has also `useEffect(async func...)` and it pre-fetches the products for the home page.
Now `ProductDetail` is just to show the details for an individual product. By the "component doesn't render", I mean ProductDetails component breaks if I directly hit the url with a `productId`

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? Is there an error?

Comment: The error says `can't read property title of undefined`, meaning the product is not fetched for which it is trying to render `product.title`

Comment: Well, of course, if you start loading the product when the component is rendered for the first time, it's not going to be in the store yet. You'll need to handle that case separately, e.g. in the simplest way `if (!product) { return <p>Loading</p> }`

Comment: as far as I know, the `useEffect` will get called first before the rendering happens, but I don't see that method being called or any network call to fetch the products.

Comment: Got it, you are right, I should handle this case separately since it is not letting the component render. Thank you.

Comment: Hooks are fired *when* a component renders. The component doesn't *wait* for the action's result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the product will not be in the store yet when directly navigating to the `ProductDetail` component. The `useEffect` hook initiates the loading of the product, but until that finishes, `product` will be undefined (or null, or something else depending on your reducer). You'll need to handle this case separately.

The most simple way to handle it is to render a loading indicator of some sort, e.g.

```
export const ProductDetail = ({ match }) => {
  const productId = match.params.productId;
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchProductById(productId));
  }, [productId, dispatch]);

  const product = useSelector((state) => selectProductById(state, productId));

  if (!product) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }

  return(<.....>)
}
```

Additionally, as also mentioned in the comments, hooks in general fire *when* a component renders. The component does not wait for an action initiated by the `useEffect` hook to finish. From [React's docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

> The function passed to `useEffect` will run after the render is committed to the screen.